How to add Search Filed Required in Wordpress Search and Filter Pluggin shortcode?
[searchandfilter fields="search,category," submit_label ="Search" search_placeholder="Number" all_items_labels=",Select a Catagory, All Countries" headings="Number,Catagory"]
here how can i make search filed required?
i expect when someone try to search and filter something then must be fillup search field. without completing search flied no result will be displayed.

In default Search & Filter does not have any option to make it required. So we need to write some custom code for this situation.
Please add this script to your custom script.
Add in search.php
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        console.log(jQuery('[name="_sf_search[]"]').length)
        jQuery('[name="_sf_search[]"]').prop('required', true);
    });
</script>

Add in function.php
<?php
function custom_search_filter_script()
{
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {      
      console.log(jQuery('[name="_sf_search[]"]').length)
      jQuery('[name="_sf_search[]"]').prop('required', true);
    });
  </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_search_filter_script');


this script don't work for me.

@MD.EhatesaMulHoquePiash I have updated code please let me know what you get in console?

when i put 2nd script in function.php and click save then it shows me syntax error.

i use this code it;s updated successfully but search filed still not required-function custom_search_filter_script()
{
echo <<<HTML

HTML;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_search_filter_script');

@MD.EhatesaMulHoquePiash after added my latest code what you get logged in console?

Or please share url where you have added the code

Thank You So much, I fixed it another way. thank you so so much for your warm response.
